# How to make react component with numerous form fields change state in a more efficient way?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-forms

I have a component with about 16 input fields. The component itself is quite complex. The problem is that every time it updates the state of the form on input change it triggers a re-render. Rendering that component is a bit expensive, there is a short delay noticeable when you type a character inside an input.

What is best practice in such a case?

Maybe I should update the state only when the user submits the form?

Comment: use `react-hook-form` :/

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to use any other library that manages form state,

you can move the `form` to another `component`, in this case only the child `component` that conains your `form` will rerender on changing `inputs` values, not the parent `component`, and pass to it the `function` that handles `submit` in `props` to trigger changes in the parent `component` when you `submit` the `form`